# how to select positions of a matrix to average in python?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a matrix with shape (1,517) and I want to average only the first 11 elements, counting from 0, that is 0,1,2,3, etc.

I've tried with np.mean (Times [idx]) where idx are the positions of the values I want to average

```py
print(times)
array([[1.55079361e+09, 1.55079377e+09, 1.55079394e+09, 1.55079410e+09,
        1.55079430e+09, 1.55079446e+09, 1.55079462e+09, 1.55079479e+09,
        1.55079495e+09, 1.55079512e+09, 1.55079528e+09, 1.55079544e+09,
        1.55079561e+09, 1.55079577e+09, 1.55079594e+09, 1.55079614e+09,
        1.55079630e+09, 1.55079646e+09, 1.55079663e+09, 1.55079679e+09,
        1.55079695e+09, 1.55079712e+09, 1.55079728e+09, 1.55079744e+09,
        1.55079761e+09, 1.55079781e+09, 1.55079797e+09, 1.55079814e+09,
        1.55079830e+09, 1.55079846e+09, 1.55079863e+09, 1.55079879e+09,
        1.55079895e+09, 1.55079912e+09, 1.55079928e+09, 1.55079945e+09,
        1.55079964e+09, 1.55079981e+09, 1.55079997e+09, 1.55080014e+09,
        1.55080030e+09, 1.55080046e+09, 1.55080063e+09, 1.55080079e+09,
        1.55080096e+09, 1.55080112e+09, 1.55080128e+09, 1.55080148e+09,
        1.55080164e+09, 1.55080181e+09, 1.55080197e+09, 1.55080214e+09,
        1.55080230e+09, 1.55080246e+09, 1.55080263e+09, 1.55080279e+09,
        1.55087981e+09]])

idx = mlab.find((tiempos>=1550793600) & (tiempos<1550795400))
print(idx)
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10], dtype=int64)
np.mean(times[idx])
```

I want to average the values of the data that are in the idx positions, i am new here and I am confused, I hope you can help me, I will be very grateful

Comment: the average of first 11 elements is required or average of `idx`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's because you have a nested array, means an array inside an array, i.e. an array of lenght 57 inside an array of lenght 1.

```
len(times)
#Output
1

len(times[0])
#Output
57
```

So what you did is right, just do it on `times[0]`:

```
times = times[0]
```

Now your code will work

```
idx = mlab.find((tiempos>=1550793600) & (tiempos<1550795400))
np.mean(times[idx])
#Output
1550794449.090909
```

Comment: I'm glad. Than upvote and select it as best answer ;-)